# PHPMailer script sending email twice when CC added

Tags: php, email, duplicates, smtp, phpmailer

I'm trying to send an email that has a attachment generated using dompdf to a list of recipients. Using `array_shift()` for taking the primary email and remove it from the array and use `foreach` for taking every other email as CC. When I'm adding CC, email is sent twice. If there is no CC, it will be sent only once. Even if CC is blank , it is sent twice. If I remove that line `AddCC()`, it will be sent only once.

Any idea or help I can seek?

```
require_once 'dompdf/autoload.inc.php';
require_once 'phpqrcode/qrlib.php';

require 'PHPMailer/src/Exception.php';
require 'PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
require 'PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

$recipients = array() // array of emails to be sent
try {

    ob_start();
    include "pdf.php";
    $htmldata = ob_get_clean();
    
    $options = new Dompdf\Options();
    $options->getChroot($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
    $options->setisRemoteEnabled(true);
    $options->setIsHtml5ParserEnabled(true);
    $options->setTempDir('temp'); // temp folder with write permission

    $dompdf = new Dompdf\Dompdf($options);
    
    $dompdf->loadHtml($htmldata);
    
    $customPaper = array(0,0,600,600);
    $dompdf->set_paper($customPaper);
    
    QRcode::png($data, "qr.png", "L", 4, 4);
    
    $dompdf->render();
    $output = $dompdf->output();

    //Server settings
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 1; // Enable verbose debug output
    $mail->isSMTP(); // Set mailer to use SMTP
    $mail->Host = ''; // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true; // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username = ''; // SMTP username
    $mail->Password = ''; // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls'; // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
    $mail->Port = 587; // TCP port to connect to


    $mail->setFrom('', '');
    $mail->addAddress(array_shift($recipients)); // Add first email as the recipient and remove the email from array
    $mail->addReplyTo('');
    foreach($recipients as $ccEmail)
    {
        $mail->AddCC($ccEmail);
    }

    $mail->addStringAttachment($output, 'attachment.pdf');
    
    $mail->isHTML(true); // Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = 'Subject'.rand();
    $mail->Body = 'Content';
    $mail->AltBody = 'content';
    
    $mail->send();
    echo 'Message has been sent';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
}
```

Comment: Good code indentation would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: Either you have described the problem badly (or I read it badly) Or this is not reproducible [See Demo](https://3v4l.org/rDlVo)

Comment: _Useful Note (I hope_  Most mail hosts will not send an email if the from address does not exist, or it is not an address on their system that they can verify so `$mail->setFrom('', '');` woudl need to be filled in

Comment: I do notice `$recipients = array()` which I assume is you removing the list of emails. But that line does not have a `;` and would therefore be generating a `Parse error: syntax error, ....`  Please remember, when the issue is not obvious we look deeply at your code and spot all the little issues in case they are relevant which can sometimes make people just move on and ignore the question:)

Comment: @RiggsFolly Thanks. I will check the link you mentioned. Also the missing semicolon was just accidentally removed when I added the code here. I have removed the emails from the code, so thats why the setFrom, addresses are all blank.